# Terraform setting Route53 NS record never completes

Tags: terraform, amazon-route53, terraform-provider-aws

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "fix-ns" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name    = var.domain_name
  type    = "NS"
  ttl     = "30"
  records = ["ns-1999.awsdns-57.co.uk", "ns-1031.awsdns-00.org", "ns-688.awsdns-22.net", "ns-325.awsdns-40.com"]
}
```

I want my Route53 NS record to match a known set of DNS NS records, so I've added the above resource. My automation IAM user has `AmazonRoute53FullAccess`. We get as far as `aws_route53_record.fix-ns: Creating...` ok, it throws no errors, but it never completes.

Suggestions as to why?

Edit: It's just occurred to me that I never see a `Still creating...` message for this resource, it just block further resource creations down the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add `allow_overwrite = true` to the resource.

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "fix-ns" {
  allow_overwrite = true
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name    = var.domain_name
  type    = "NS"
  ttl     = "30"
  records = ["ns-1999.awsdns-57.co.uk", "ns-1031.awsdns-00.org", "ns-688.awsdns-22.net", "ns-325.awsdns-40.com"]
}
```

Weirdly I worked this out by doing a targeted deploy `terraform apply -target=aws_route53_record.fix-ns`. The resource was failing but the error did not surface in the full apply run, the targeted run allowed the error to surface. Which feels like a bug report :o

Comment: The symptoms you describe (i.e. inconsistency between "global" apply and a targeted one) indeed make me think this might be some Terraform bug.
Or things are not deterministic on AWS end. I mean - the error on their server side might come and go.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a stab in the dark, but...

I suspect it's actually failing for you, but [the default retry count `max_retries = 25`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#max_retries) kicks in and you don't see the error message. The retry mechanism there has exponential back-off (which is good for other reasons), so the `25` retries take several minutes to conclude.

Try setting `max_retries` to `1` or `2` and observe the outcome (which I guess will be an error).

Comment: Good to know this is an option, but sadly still didn't surface my error. I had to do an `apply target` on the problem resource before I got any error message.